# generate a hex file by converting strings into hex from a text file in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Python tool that generates a text file in which each line has a string. I want to generate a hex file using this text file. The file has lines the following line:

```
-5.139488050547036391e-01
3.181812818225058681e+00

475.465798764

abc[0]
abc[0]*abc[10]
```

I tried using `binascii.hexlify(b'<String>')`, which works when I manually enter the strings, but when I do that:

```
with open("strings.txt", "r") as a_file:
  for line in a_file:
    if not line.strip():
        continue
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    hex_= binascii.hexlify(b'<'+ stripped_line +'>')
    print(hex_)
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't concat str to bytes
```

How can I convert those strings of different types into hex and generate a .hex file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a `string` (line in file)  to `bytes` object you have to encode it. In your case, that only means to replace this line from your code

```
hex_= binascii.hexlify(b'<'+ stripped_line +'>')
```

with this line

```
hex_= binascii.hexlify(stripped_line.encode())
```

Your code ran into error, because you tried to concatenate `'b<'` (**byte** object) with `stripped_line` (**string** object) and it has no meaning in python.

Comment: Should I save the hex as a string in the .hex file?  `    with open('strings.hex', 'a') as hexfile:
        hexfile.write(str(hex_)+'\n')` , if yes how to use `binascii.unhexlify` later to convert them back to strings?

Comment: You can save the generated `hex` as it is and you can also save it as a `string`. You can choose a way depending on your requirements.  If you choose to save it as a string, you can just use `decode` method to convert `bytes` to `string` like this: `hex_.decode()`.  If you choose to save it as it is, you don't need to do any conversions, instead you'll have to open file in `binary` mode like this: `open('strings.hex', 'ab')`. File writing process remains same.